# PHP - how to generate a URL on save like JSFiddle does?

Tags: php, subdomain

I'm trying to recreate something you might know from imgur or jsfiddle - you just type something or upload images, then you click "save" or "upload" and then you get a original link in form of imgur.com/smth or jsfiddle.net/smth. How is this done? I've created simple website where I can write notes and save them and it works perfectly well for myself, but I wanted to share it with some of my friends and I have absolutely no idea how can the "save" button attach their changes to new URL every time they press it? I know this is pretty basic but I couldn't find anything on the matter online and I really have no idea how to handle this issue, excepting I'll be writing their changes to different SQL rows.

Thanks for any clues :)

Comment: Google `permalink` or `seo optimized url` for php and you'll find plenty of material. Some of the php frameworks have that feature also, so if you are using any php framework you can investigate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to create something and let people edit it and keep the same link you could do it with PHP and mySQL.

I think the easiest way would be to have one page to create the initial note and one to update/view it. Once you create it the save button would add it to a database with a unique id of some kind like an auto increment number. To send the page you would use a link like www.somepage.com/info.php?id=1. The "id=1" part would be the unique id within the database. In info.php, you would need to use  $get_["id"] and set that to equal the database id row and load the info from there. Then you could allow edits to that row from that page. You would have to set the save button to update the row.

To get something like somepage.com/smith, if you're on a linux server, you would use htaccess and mod_rewrite.

This is a really down and dirty gist of how you could do this, but it should send you in the right direction.